Does apache camel support AWS SQS temporary queues?
So I discovered that there is a thing called Amazon SQS temporary queues. So I'm just wondering, does Apache Camel framework support this feature, and how does it work with request-response pattern?
So I tried to search for it but didn't get any results. I also tried to check camel code, but it didn't end well either
